# Leetcode 5 Longest Palindromic Substring (python)

Tags: python, substring, palindrome

Why do I get wrong answer using this code? I try to find all possible substrings and find the longest one after storing them into a list. Thank you for your help!

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        
            length  = len(s)
            #get all possible substrings
            combinations = [s[i:j] for i in range(length) for j in range(i+1, length+1)]

            #print(combinations)

            rev = s[::-1]
            rev_combinations = [rev[i:j] for i in range(length) for j in range(i+1, length+1)]

            #print(rev_combinations)

            pan_l = []
            for i, c in enumerate(combinations)):
                if combinations[i] == rev_combinations[i]:
                    pan_l.append(combinations[i])
            
            if pan_l:
                y = max(pan_l, key=len)
                return y
            else:
                return s[0]
```

Comment: I personally don't think these types of ps questions should be asked in StackOverflow and I believe your question can receive more interest when posted on a more related community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the string `"ab"`. This will give `combinations == ['a', 'ab', 'b']`. Its reverse, `"ba"`, gives `rev_combinations == ['b', 'ba', 'a']`. You see that none of the items match at their exact positions, even though `'a'` and `'b'` are both trivial palindromes.

A better way to deal with this would be to check each substring if it is a palindrome:

```
pan_l = []
for substring in combinations:
    if substring == substring[::-1]: # this substring is a palindrome
        pan_l.append(substring)
```

You then don't need `rev` or `rev_combinations` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've so much to work on on coding!

Answer (score 0):

Jasmin provides the reason your code is incorrect.

One fix is to define rev_combinations as:

```
#rev = s[::-1]  # Remove this line
# reverse substrings using s[i:j][::-1]
rev_combinations = [s[i:j][::-1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i+1, length+1)]
```

Now your code works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day (: